# Symmetric vs Symmetrical

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, symmetry

I was reading an engineering book.

It says " A turbomachine with symmetrical velocity triangles...".
I personally felt more naturally right away to say symmetric velocity triangles.

What is the difference? if there is one at all.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/usage-of-symmetrical-and-symmetric#:~:text=%22Symmetrical%22%20is%20a%20non%2D,Lisi's%20comment%20under%20the%20question).

Comment: I think they are synonyms. [Wikipedia lists "symmetrical" as a definition of "symmetric"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symmetric#Adjective).

Comment: *Symmetric* is more usual in this context, but they are synonymous.

Comment: It seems that the ESE reference contradicts the usage you see in this engineering book.  Looking at a "usage over time" it appears that "symmetrical" reached its height of popularity in the mid 20th century, while "symmetric" has more recently reached a height of popularity...

Comment: I saw the post on the english SEx, but thought of asking to the mathematicians. As math requires rigorous definitions.

Comment: Evidently, Merriam Webster list symmetrical as the main entry.  If Wikipedia and MW disagree, my initial suspicion is that it is a American English vs British English issue.

Comment: somewhat related: 'resultant' versus 'resulting'